# npm run start has something wrong

Tags: javascript, npm

```
{
    "name": "webdiff",
    "version": "0.0.5",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node ./bin/start",
        "build": "webpack --color --config webpack.config.js",
        "deploy": "npm run build && node writeHtml.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.3.4",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.4",
        "antd": "^4.4.2",
        "classnames": "^2.2.6",
        "diff": "^4.0.2",
        "ejs": "^3.1.9",
        "express": "^4.16.4",
        "http-errors": "^1.6.2",
        "morgan": "^1.9.1",
        "react": "^16.8.3",
        "react-dom": "^16.8.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.8.3",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.10.4",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.3.4",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
        "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
        "babel-plugin-import": "^1.13.0",`your text`
        "css-loader": "^6.9.0",
        "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.5",
        "source-map-loader": "^1.0.1",
        "webpack": "^5.0.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.2.3"
    }
}
```

[image]
[image]

it seems the webpack version is wrong but i dont know how to fix it, please help, thank you`

Comment: Add all information as text not as image

Comment: seems `npm i` has the issue, yo haven't even tried `npm run start` - note: read the error message. it has suggestions to circumvent the issue

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

run command `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` instead of `npm install`

it will show some warnings but will install everything , this kind of error happens when some of your 3rd party packages requires different versions of another package , its normal to happen just use `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` instead of `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

Find a dependency error after running the command npm audit fix --force.
After that you shoud use npm install --legacy-peer-deps instead of npm install.